# Visual Studio the shortcut that displays conditionals and loops

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I haven't written code in C# for about 8 month so I came back now, but there was many shortcut that I used to use a lot. Despite this I've forgotten it So as far as I remember When you use the shortcut which displays all conditional and loops and also some more things like region.

I wonder if a person that knows all these shortcut could say me it ?

Comment: Are you referring to code folding?

Comment: regions (and other similar keywords) are triggered with `#` and conditional... `breakpoints`? are when you make a breakpoint and right click it

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the insert snippet shortcut => CTRL+K and then S.

[code snippets](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat.aspx)

Comment: Yes This one was the shotcut I meant, Thanks